# How to combine 2 array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 arrays of objects, I want to combine both array of objects as one array, by adding 2nd arrays key value pair as 3rd key value pairs for 1st array.

First array

```
 a = [{:performed_at=>"Aging", :result=>"Not Completed"}, {:performed_at=>"Aging", :result=>"Not Completed"}, {:performed_at=>"Mar 25, 2022", :result=>"Pass"}]
```

Second Array

```
b = [{:line_item=>"10C-1648150055"}, {:line_item=>"10D-1648150055"}, {:line_item=>"10E-1648150055"}]
```

I want the result array of objects like this

```
[{:performed_at=>"Aging", :result=>"Not Completed", :line_item=>"10C-1648150055"}, {:performed_at=>"Aging", :result=>"Not Completed",:line_item=>"10D-1648150055"}, {:performed_at=>"Mar 25, 2022", :result=>"Pass",:line_item=>"10E-1648150055"}]
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the this should work:

```rb
a.map.with_index do |el, index|
 el.merge(b[index])
end
```